# Regex is that will match commented SQL code

Tags: java, regex

How to write a Java regular expression for a commented SQL code like below?

```
/*
    SELECT * FROM Table1;
    -- Comment in comment
    Another SQL code
*/
SQL-code
-- One line comment
/**/ -- Yet one comment
/* And yet one comment */
```

This is my current wrong variant: `(--.*)|(/\*(.*\n)*\*/)`.

I know that comment signatures (`--`, `/**/`) can be inside string but for my purpose we can consider so strings as comments, it doesn't matter. The most important to exclude all commented SQL code.

Comment: Is this to protect against SQL injection?

Comment: @VLAZ nope, to build diagram from procedures which tables are used inside procedure body, so I need to remove commented SQL code to analyzer didn't extract table names from comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this pattern for matching comments:

```
(?s)(?:\/\*.*?\*\/|--[^\n]*)
```

Explanation:

`(?s)` - single line mode, `.` matches newline

`(?:...)` - non-capturing group

`\/\*` - match `/*` literally

`.*?` - match zero or more of any characters (non-greedy)

`\*\/` - match `*/` literally

`|` - alterantion - match pattern on the left side or on the right side of it

`--` - match `--` literally

`[^\n]*` - match zero or more characters other from newline character

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/KM8IPK/1)

Comment: Thank you, for my task it works perfectly. And special thank for explanation)